# Mostrar números repetidos JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando hacer un programa en Javascript que muestre el numero más repetido y cuantas veces aparece el número más repetido. El código es el siguiente:

```
var numbers = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,7,8];

var repeated = numbers.reduce((counter, value) => {if(!counter[value]) counter[value] = 1; else counter[value]++; return counter}, []);

repeated.forEach((replays,number) => console.log(number, '=>', replays));
```

Se supone que la salida me debería dar lo siguiente:

```
Longest:4
Number:1
```

Comment: Tu código parece estar bien, solo te faltaría otro `.reduce()` que devuelva el elemento con más repeticiones.

Comment: @Triby ¿Y donde iría el otro reduce? sería algo asi? repeated.reduce(forEach((replays,number) => console.log(number, '=>', replays)));

Answer (score 1):

Tu código actual está armando un arreglo donde el índice corresponde al número y el valor a la cantidad de veces que se repite. Necesitas aplicar otro `.reduce()` para obtener solo el número que se repitió más veces y puedes hacerlo con objetos o con arreglo.

En este ejemplo, se genera un arreglo de dos elementos: `[número, repeticiones]`.

```js
let numbers = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,7,8,];

// Estás armando un arreglo tipo: número (índice) = repeticiones (cantidad)
let repeated = numbers.reduce((counter, value) => {
    if(!counter[value])
        counter[value] = 1;
    else
        counter[value]++;
    return counter;
},[]);

// Reducir para obtener solo el que se repitió más veces
// Parámetros:
// - acum    Arreglo [número, repeticiones]
// - value   Elemento actual (repeticiones)
// - index   Elemento actual (número)
let max = repeated.reduce((acum, value, index) => {
    // Si el valor actual es mayor
    return (value > acum[1])
        // Devolver número y valor actual
        ? [index, value]
        // Devolver acumulador
        : acum;
}, [0, 0]); // Inicializar acumulador con número y repeticiones en cero

// max[0] es el número más repetido
// max[1] es la cantidad de veces que se repitió
console.log(max);
```

**Nota:** Recuerda que los métodos de arreglos (como `.reduce()`) recorren internamente cada elemento y ejecutan la función proporcionada, por lo que no es necesario (ni conveniente, en la mayoría de los casos) recorrer dentro con `.forEach()`.

Answer (score 0):

Todo con un solo `.reduce` sería algo como esto:

```js
const numbers = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

const res = numbers.reduce((p, c) => {

  p[0][c] = p[0][c] + 1 || 1; // <-- Si ya existe el número se suma 1 sino se agrega con el valor 1

  if (p[0][c] > p[1]) { // <-- Si supera el máximo actual se actualiza el numero y e máximo
    p[1] = p[0][c];
    p[2] = c;
  }

  return p;

}, [{}, 0, 0]);

console.log("Longest:", res[1]);
console.log("Number:", res[2]);
```

Podemos usar como objeto inicial del reduce `[{},[],[]]`, en donde el primer elemento es un objeto que almacena las cantidades de cada número.